# Using pdf.js exception occur JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): PDFJS is not defined

Tags: gwt, pdf.js

```
    **In html file add script tag**



         <head>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
             <button id="prev" onclick="goPrevious()">Previous</button>
                <button id="next" onclick="goNext()">Next</button>
                &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> 
                 <span id="page_count"></span></span>
              </div>

             <div>
                <canvas id="the-canvas" width="700" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
              </div>
            </body>
```

**and in client side (pdf.java) call a java script funcion using JSNI alse paste pdf.js file in public folder and call .gwt.xml like**

```
**I am just follow this link http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/1/edit**






            public void onModuleLoad() {
                alert1();
                }


            private native void alert1 ()
            /*-{
        var url = 'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf';

        PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

        var pdfDoc = null,
            pageNum = 1,
            scale = 0.8,
            canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function renderPage(num) {
            // Using promise to fetch the page
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
                var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: ctx,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
            });


            document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
            document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
        }


        function goPrevious() {
            if (pageNum <= 1) return;
            pageNum--;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        }



        function goNext() {
            if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) return;
            pageNum++;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        }



        PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
            pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        });​

            }-*/;
```

11:27:17.679 [ERROR] [pdf] Unable to load module entry point class com.ruchi.client.Pdf (see associated exception for details)
        com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): PDFJS is not defined
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
            at com.ruchi.client.Pdf.alert1(Pdf.java)
            at com.ruchi.client.Pdf.onModuleLoad(Pdf.java:27)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
            at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
    plz suggest me what i do....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just blindly copy pasting javascript code into JSNI block.

Example if in your html js block you have

```
function test() {
  alert('hello');  
}
```

In your JSNI

```
private static native int test() /*-{
    var v = $wnd.test();
    return v;
  }-*/;
```

*Do you notice the use of* **$wnd**

1) HTML should have

```
    <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> of <span id="page_count"></span></span>
    <div>
        <canvas id="the-canvas" width="700" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
    </div>
```

2) Move pdf.js to local folder ( aovid script tag in html file requesting over internet )

3) Instead add `<script src="PDF.js" />` in your module.gwt.xml file. Copy https://raw.github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js into your GWT's **public** folder.

4) Modify your JSNI code

```
/*-{
    var url = 'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf';

    $wnd.PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

    var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        scale = 0.8,
        canvas =  $wnd.document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function renderPage(num) {
        // Using promise to fetch the page
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
            var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });


       $wnd.document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
       $wnd.document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    }
    function goPrevious() {
        if (pageNum <= 1) return;
        pageNum--;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    function goNext() {
        if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) return;
        pageNum++;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    $wnd.PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
        pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    });​
    }-*/;
```

5) You should be able to solve Next/Prev similarly. Avoid raising one more question to solve that. You should try doing some "HOMEWork"

Comment: Note: `<script>` within gwt.xml doesn't work with the `xsiframe` linker, and that linker is the future (understand: probably the only one that will be updated, and could replace the `std` linker as the default linker in the future). One should either use a `<script>` in the host page or `ScriptInjector` (either `FromUrl`, or `FromString` in combination with a `TextResource`).

Comment: @Thomas Would that be for new Super Dev Mode or even for normal Hosted mode?

Comment: Nothing to do with dev vs. super-dev vs. prod mode.

Comment: @SSR mam as u say firstly i read so many doc of jsni but i can't understand how to call javascript function inside jsni.this is my first project using jsni in gwt and in this project i m using pdf.js..so plz help me...thanx in adance..

Comment: The above code snippets brings up the pdf ( only Next/Prev buttons are not visible ) you would need some more jsni stuff for that. Does that  address your question.

Comment: yes, i get pdf but for next and back button click how to call internal function within jsni? I read lots of documents and blog nut didn't get answer.

Answer (score 1):

[JSNI 101](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing): you have to use `$wnd.PDFJS` instead of `PDFJS`.